# How to make generated ViewDataBinding subclasses implement an interface

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have two data binding layouts that `<include>` the same shared layout and assign it the same ID. I'd like to use a single code path to access the shared sub-binding on both `android.databinding.ViewDataBinding` subclasses. Is this possible?

My use case is refactorting from something like this:

```
binding.sub1 = subBinding.foo = bar
binding.sub2 = subBinding.foo = bar
binding.sub3 = subBinding.foo = bar
```

to this:

```
for (subBinding in ...) {
   subBinding.foo = bar
}
```

Comment: You can directly use shared layouts and assign values to it. Why do you want to subclass `ViewDataBinding`?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I want to implement a common interface, not extend a common subclass. Added an explanation of my use case to my original question, let me know if whether that makes sense.